# Apache virtual hosts don't seem to be working

Tags: apache, dns, apache2

I've set up files for my sites' virtual hosts in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. I've created a file called mysite.com and inside I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin email@mail.com
     ServerName mysite.com
     ServerAlias mysite.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Yet when I visit the actual domain with a web browser, it seems to be serving `/var/www/index.html`. My DNS is doing a frame redirect to my servers IP address. What else do I need to do for this to work?

I'm new to hosting my own sites.

Comment: What do you mean by "your DNS is doing a frame redirect"? Virtual hosts require that the DNS entry for mysite.com points to your server, and not to somebody else who has a full-screen frame showing your server's IP address.

Comment: When I HTTP redirect to my IP address my IP shows in the browser's address bar, though. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yeah, so I just changed them to HTTP redirects and now it can't even find the web server. I type the domain name in my address bar and it resolves as the literal IP address of my server and says that it could not connect.

Comment: apache looks at the Host: header of the request to find out what virtual host to use. If you redirect to your IP address, you've lost that header and you won't get to your vhost.

Comment: So how do I send a header telling it which host to use?

Comment: If it helps, I'm doing all of this on a Linode VPS and my hosting service is 1&1.

Comment: The browser does that: when you request myhost.com, it not only looks up the IP, it also tells the server at that IP that it was looking for myhost.com (via the Host: header). Can you tell us what the commandline output of `host myhost.com` is?

Answer (score 6):

you need to enable this virtual host + reload apache config:

```
# a2ensite mysite.com
# apache2ctl graceful
```

Comment: Hmm, so I did that and I see the entries for my sites in sites-enabled but it's still serving /var/www/index.html. When I do 'sudo service apache2 restart' I get this back, if it helps at all.

     * Restarting web server apache2                                                    apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified     domain name, using {MY IP ADDRESS} for ServerName
    apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully     qualified domain name, using {MY IP ADDRESS} for ServerName
    Action 'start' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more info

Comment: to fix "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name" you need to do this: # echo ServerName localhost >> /etc/apache2/conf.d/httpd.conf (debian)

Comment: Thanks. That error is gone. It still just says 
"* Restarting web server apache2                                                Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information." now.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a few days, and what eventually helped was disabling the default virtual host. In ubuntu 14/apache 2.4 you'll see "000-default.conf" in the sites-enabled directory

so

```
a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

Also mind the .conf extension, it is mandatory